# Retaining modified values inside and outside of if-else statements?

Tags: c++, if-statement

My current background in C++ is I've taken a college level course for a semester.

I'm having troubles figuring out how to make the values I assign inside if-else statements retain outside of it. I figured if I declare it beforehand outside and use pointers to handle the memory addresses themselves, it would be fair game, but apparently not.

my "MAZE" file for now:

```
. # # # # # # 
. . . . . # # 
# . # # . # # 
# . # # . . # 
# . . # # . # 
# . # # . . # 
# . # # . # # 
. . . # . . . 
# # . . . # #
```

And this is what I have inside of my maze.h file, defining the constructor. I haven't gotten around to most of the program yet, but my main.cpp already handles calculating the text file's maze dimensions, and then it just calls

`Maze *testMaze = new Maze(rows,columns);`

My maze.h file has bool maze[0][0] listed as a private member. It's set to 0 because at code's first execution, there is no way to know the size of the maze yet. I run code to calculate the size, and then pass the rows and columns in as parameters in the Maze constructor.

My maze.cpp file's constructor with parameters:

```
Maze::Maze(int rows, int columns)
{
    string mazeRow="";
    int roIndex=0; //Row Index
    int coIndex=0; //Column Index
    bool maze[rows][columns];
    bool* target = NULL;

    ifstream input;
    input.open("MAZE",ios::in);
    if(input)
    {

        while (getline(input, mazeRow))
        {
            //Testprint this row of the maze.
            cout << mazeRow << endl; //mazeRow is the data in that row of the text file.
            //Store each non-space value.


            for (coIndex=0; coIndex<mazeRow.length(); coIndex++) //For each character in that row...
            {
                char check=mazeRow[coIndex];
                target = &maze[roIndex][coIndex];   
                if (check=='.') //Path
                {
                    *target=true;
                cout << *target << " "; //These print statements print correctly.
                }
                else if (check=='#') //Wall
                {
                    *target=false;
                cout << *target << " "; //These print statements print correctly.
                }
                else if (check==' ') //Space
                {
                //ignore spaces
                }
                else //For all other cases, an invalid character is present.
                {
                    cout << "Invalid character detected." << endl;
                }
                cout << *target << " "; //For some odd reason, this line BY ITSELF doubles up print. Ex. instead of printing 1 1 0 1 0, it would print 1 1 1 1 0 0 1 1 0 0.
            }
        cout << "End of row." << endl;
        roIndex++;
        }
    }
    input.close();

    cout << "Storage completed." << endl;

    for (int i=0; i<rows; i++)
    {
    cout << "Row " << i << endl;
        for (int j=0; j<columns; j++)
        {
        /* This is the print test to see if the values 
           are retained outside of the first block. 
           None of them print the maze file properly.
        */
        if (maze[i][j] == true)
            cout << maze[i][j] << "\t" << "." << "\t";
        if (maze[i][j] == false)
            cout << maze[i][j] << "\t" << "#" << "\t";
        cout << "Column " << j << endl;
        }
        cout << "End of row." << endl;
    }
    cout << "Verification completed." << endl;
}
```

First time asking a question here, so if I'm missing anything, let me know.

---

Just wanted to put up an update here. Turns out, I was either overly stressed, sleep deprived, or both. I put down this code for a few hours and took a new look at it, and I found so many logic errors in my code, including but not limited to forgetting why certain variables existed and what they were used for, not thinking clearly on all the aftereffects of incrementing (++) within a loop, and otherwise sloppy mistakes like those. I've taken several of the answers/comments below and refreshed my understanding of my own code, helping me correct these errors. When I get around to it, I'll supply a finished code if I can.

---

Solved the problem. I'll be able to self-answer in a few hours and explain what actually happened then.

Comment: does this even compile? `bool maze[rows][columns];` should give a compile time error since you need to specify constants when declaring array sizes

Comment: @msam Many compilers have supported variable sized arrays for quite some time, even if they're non-standard. Variable sized arrays are also part of the C standard I believe, not sure if it made it into C++11 standard though.

Comment: It's a good idea to reduce your examples to something more manageable. Something that just illustrates the core of your question/problem. It's a lot easier for people to understand what you're having trouble with that way.

Comment: You ask about retaining values assigned inside if-else statements outside of these. And then you go on about pointers, memory addresses and maze dimensions. What is your actual question?

Comment: Do you know how to use if control statements? Because whatever that thing prints out is valid as far as your controls are concerned. And why would u write something like maze[i][j] == true?

Comment: It's probably a good idea to avoid using pointers at all in C++ until you have a good understanding of what they are and when they are necessary.  In this case, they are just making your code needlessly complicated.  You will also find it a lot easier to use `std::vector` instead of an array for `maze`.

Comment: My overall question is, want the values I stored within the if-elseif-elseif-else region to stick with me later in the code. The bottom portion is ONLY to test-print what the current/latest values in the matrix are, and they're clearly not the values I tried to store in there. I've already learned a big portion of information about pointers, and when to use them, but at this point, I'm trying just about anything just to get my code to function how I need it. I was considering using a vector, but the instructions I am given require me to use an array.

Comment: I've seen some questions here with skimpy generic code leading to unanswerable questions, so I figured I'd toss my whole code in here just to be safe. I just want to know how I can store values inside if-else statements and still have those stored values accessible later on. The code after "Storage Completed" only exists there as sample testcode requesting the values in the matrix, and based on the output, I know that I'm not getting the boolean values I stored in there.

Comment: @MichaelAnderson good point, thanks, too used to developing on MSVC. (and variable sized arrays are still not in the C++11 standard)

Answer (score 0):

Member variables.

---

<sup>Serious advice: Learn basic C++ first before getting into pointers, memory adresses, classes, et cetera.</sup>

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure what you're trying to acheive here or actually what the problem is that you're trying to get help with.

You've highlighted a line which is not doing what you'd expect:

```
 cout << *target << " "; //For some odd reason, this line BY ITSELF doubles up print. Ex. instead of printing 1 1 0 1 0, it would print 1 1 1 1 0 0 1 1 0 0.
```

However, this line is only outputting a bool so if changed to:

```
cout << "[" << *target << "] ";
```

it gives:

```
. # # # # # #  
1 [1] [254] 0 [0] [72] 0 [0] [0] 0 [0] [0] 0 [0] [77] 0 [0] [90] 0 [0] [0] [32] End of row.
```

Now you can see that since your code outputs the line read in and then iterates over that line, firstly outputting 1 if the character is a '.' and 0 if the character is a '#' but otherwise you do not assign a value so the `1 [1] [254]` at the beginning of the line is reading the first '.' character (`1 [1]`) and then ignoring a space (`[254]`)

(note that you didn't publish code to assign initial values to your matrix of bools - not sure whether you're doing this, but you're certainly using the values in the matrix for output without necessarily setting them in this code. This explains the odd integer values.)

Thus it isn't doubling up but just doing what you've asked it to. Perhaps you need to look at all the paths your code can take through the conditionals?

Comment: The cout you mentioned that I highlighted: I'll do another test with brackets, but the last time I ran the code, if I comment out all the couts above it, it doesn't print the random numbers. Just doubled 1's and 0's.

Comment: @Alex Mai: I commented out all the couts within the for loop except this one and it printed out 15 seperate numbers - which is exactly the size of your input string due spaces being interleaved into it.

Comment: Oh wait, hmm... Now I'm a tad confused. I know one of my dozens of tests came out with duplicated values. I'm getting similar results to what you're getting. The spaces don't print anything from inside the if-else, but the one outside still tries to print something. I was probably just too tired and stressed to see this thing before. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You are setting the data `target = &maze[roIndex][coIndex];` depending on the `coIndex` but in your sample data there are spaces. These are 'ignored' (not printed) but you still increment the index so you are skipping a value in the array each time:

first iteration sets `maze[0][0];`

second iteration sets nothing since you have a space

third iteration sets `maze[0][2];`

etc...

`maze[0][1];`...etc are never set

Answer (score 0):

You already are retaining the values in if(input). They're retained in the bool maze[rows][columns]; and perfectly accessible AFTER if-else. You are accessing them AFTER if-else, in the part where you re-print the maze.

I think your question should be "how to retain values from one member method (ctor) for other member methods?". The answer for this one is to store the array in member variable instead of local one.

Take phresnel advice into heart. There are no 2-dimensional arrays in C++. You can have array of arrays, that's all.

```
class CMaze
{
   int m_Rows;
   int m_Columns;
   bool** m_arrarrMazeData;

public:
   CMaze(int rows, int columns)
   {
       m_Rows = rows;
       m_Columns = colums;
       //create array of pointers, each one will store another array
       m_arrarrMazeData = new bool*[rows];

      for (int i = 0; i<rows; i++)
      {
           //create new column for every row
           m_arrarrMazeData[i] = new bool[columns];
      }
    //rest of your code here, read into m_arrarrMazeData and forget about local variables, especially bool maze[rows][columns];

   }
}
```

Comment: C++ most certainly does have multidimensional arrays.  It inherited them from C.  What do you think `int foo[5][3];` declares?

Comment: You are right, but such statically sized arrays are next to useless in real life. Like here.

Answer (score 0):

First off, thank you everyone for your help. I had originally thought the error came from issues relating to statements only modifying local copies of the variables. The final section of code below "Storage completed." was supposed to print out some form of verification that tested and printed out the array's values so that I could confirm the values in there were as I was trying to assign.

As it turns out, thanks to **Component 10**'s post, I re-analyzed my code after setting it aside for awhile, and figured out that the mistake was related to the blank spaces also running the outer cout statement. This led me to re-analyze where and how I used roIndex and coIndex, as well as question why coIndex was being used in the for-loop. It was then that I caught on and noticed that whatever variable I used in the for-loop would dictate position in the mazeRow string, while coIndex represented the column in the array. These are not to be confused with each other. **msam** caught this as well.

For example, with mazeRow[**i**] and maze[roIndex][**coIndex**]

1. mazeRow[**0**] is '.' and true would be assigned to maze[roIndex][**0**]. Increment both i++ and coIndex++.
2. mazeRow[**1**] is ' ' and nothing would be done to maze[][]. Increment i++ only.
3. mazeRow[**2**] is '#' and false would be assigned to maze[roIndex][**1**]. Increment both i++ and coIndex++.

Once I understood the source of the "extra" numbers as Component 10 explained, and cleared up my understanding of my own variable usage, the rest quickly sorted itself out. The problem had nothing to do with local copies of variables.

My current code is as follows: (Sorry for the little confusion here - the MAZE file indeed currently has an S and G to mark the start and goal of the maze.)

```
Maze::Maze(int rows, int columns)
{
    string mazeRow="";
    bool maze[rows][columns];
    for (int i=0; i<rows; i++)
    {
        for (int j=0; j<columns; j++)
        {
        maze[i][j] = false;
        }
    }
    bool* target = NULL;
    ifstream input;
    input.open("MAZE",ios::in);
    if(input)
    {
        int roIndex=0; //Row Index
        while (getline(input, mazeRow))
        {
            //Testprint this row of the maze.
            cout << mazeRow << endl; //mazeRow is the data in that row of the text file.
            //Store each non-space value.

            int coIndex=0; //Column Index
            for (int i=0; i<mazeRow.length(); i++) //For each character in that row...
            {
                char check=mazeRow[i];
                target = &maze[roIndex][coIndex];   
                if (check=='.') //Path
                {
                    *target=true;
                    coIndex++;
                }
                else if (check=='#') //Wall
                {
                    *target=false;
                    coIndex++;
                }
                else if (check=='S') //Start
                {
                    *target=true;
                    coIndex++;
                }
                else if (check=='G') //Goal
                {
                    *target=true;
                    coIndex++;
                }
                else if (check==' ') //Space
                {
                    //ignore spaces
                }
                else //For all other cases, an invalid character is present.
                {
                    cout << "Invalid character detected." << endl;
                }
            }
        roIndex++;
        }
    }
    input.close();

    cout << "Storage completed." << endl;

    for (int i=0; i<rows; i++)
    {
        for (int j=0; j<columns; j++)
        {
        cout << maze[i][j] << " ";
        }
        cout << endl;
    }
    cout << "Verification completed." << endl;
}
```

I hope this will be of help to someone in the future, and let this be a lesson: Sometimes the best solution is to put down your problem for a while and analyze what everything you've done is supposed to do versus what it's actually doing. Know why you have things, and what they need to be used for.

Comment: Using a debugger to trace through your code would also have pointed out the problem. Might be tedious but if you're trying to analyse and understand exactly what a piece of code is doing seeing things change line by line is the best way, especially if you're still learning the language